# how to build cnn model for defect detection with three classes and test one image on it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I built a CNN model to detect two kinds of defects on an image. These classes are 'big' and 'small' and the accuracy is really good. The architecture of my model is in the below:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(120, 120, 3))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(
    train_data,
    validation_data=val_data,
    epochs=100,
    callbacks=[
        tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
            monitor='val_loss',
            patience=3,
            restore_best_weights=True
        )
    ]
)
```

Now, I want to use this CNN model for multi classes and the classes would be 'big', 'small', 'other'. I have the data set, but I don't know how to change the model for three classes. Also, at the end I want to test one image to my CNN model and get the label if the inserted image is big, small or other, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape = (120, 120, 3), filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

to predict, you can use this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform

def load(filename):
    np_image = Image.open(filename)
    np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32')/255
    np_image = transform.resize(np_image, (120, 120, 3))
    np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
    return np_image


folder_path = 'Dataset/test/4.jpg'
image = load(folder_path)
pred = model.predict_classes(image)
pred.tolist()[0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but for test images, how can i get the label for output? i mean this code return the array of 0 and 1. I wrote a function that get the label but i don't know how to use it:

Comment: def generate_df(image_dir, label):

    filepaths = pd.Series(list(image_dir.glob(r'*.png')), name='Filepath').astype(str)
    labels = pd.Series(label, name='Label', index=filepaths.index)
    df = pd.concat([filepaths, labels], axis=1)
    return df

Comment: big_df = generate_df(big_dir, label="BIG")

Comment: I have changed my answer. To get predicted classes you have to use sequential.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking that tick mark sign

Comment: I have another question, if I want to change size of my data set images, which part of cnn model should change? Because I just resize input to 60*60 and when I run the sequential model to test, I got an error @AdarshWase

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. I suggest you to ask a detailed question with code and error on Stack Overflow. I am sure someone will help you.